# viewing intraday periodicity / timeframe (minute not daily bars) of stock price data using tidyquant in R

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, quantitative-finance, tidyquant

I would like to look at stock price data in R at a period smaller than daily. 1minute, 5minute, or 30minute would be ideal. I have tried working with the tq_transmute command but I cannot seem to get this working.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# using tidyverse to import a ticker
spy <- tq_get("spy")
spysegment <- tq_get("spy", get ="stock.prices", from ='2022-10-13', to = '2022-10-19')
str(spysegment)
view(spysegment)
# get 30minute data not daily
spy30m <- tq_get(c("spy"), get="stock.prices") %>%
  tq_transmute(select=close(),
               mutate_fun=to.period,
               period="minutes", n=30,
               col_rename = "minute_return") %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, minute_return)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: have you read the documentation of [`tq_get`](https://business-science.github.io/tidyquant/reference/tq_get.html)?

Comment: ""stock.prices": Get the open, high, low, close, volume and adjusted stock prices for a stock symbol from Yahoo Finance"

Comment: Yahoo data is daily. If you want sub-day financial data, you should use a different data source

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation of `tidyquant`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ01-core-functions-in-tidyquant.html#yahoo-finance) states that `get="stock.price"` downloads data from Yahoo Finance, which has daily price data.

The options for getting sub-daily information using `quantmod` include using [the Tingo API](https://www.tiingo.com/), [the Alpha Vantage API](https://www.alphavantage.co/), or [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/solution/bloomberg-terminal/). Full examples of how to use these to get sub daily stock price data can be found in the documentation.